# PhantomJS and SlimerJS fail to render some sites

Tags: phantomjs, render, slimerjs

I didn't get any output file (image) when trying to execute render_multi_url.js in phantomjs or slimerjs for some url like:

www.tamasoft.co.jp/en/general-info/unicode.html
www.bbc.co.uk

I am using the latest version of both phantomjs and slimerjs. render_multi_url.js is the original script shipped with phantomjs. Under slimerjs I get no image at all and under phantomjs I get partial image (over 9mb). Why do I get this behavior?

So what I need to change or improve to get this script working on any web page?

Comment: there is no error at all

Comment: just no image file produced

Comment: I get Rendered 'www.tamasoft.co.jp/en/general-info/unicode.html' at 'rendermulti-1.jpg' but no 'rendermulti-1.jpg in the file system

Comment: Ok, it doesn't work with slimerjs 0.9.2 on windows. I haven't found an open issue.

Comment: i am using the latest version of both phantomjs and slimerjs  
render_multi_url.js is the original script chipped with phantomjs   
under slimerjs i get nothing at all  
under phantomjs i get partial image (over 9mb)  
why i get this behavior ???

Comment: I think you should open issues on the respective github pages.

Comment: i did. it seems to be a bug in drawWindow. so we are trying to find other ways to overcame the issue

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of the issue, that SSL3 (used by default in P-js) was changed to TLS1 (or better use 'any').
To fix that you should specify the SslProtocol option.

This is the way for c#:

```
var service = PhantomJSDriverService.CreateDefaultService(driverPath);
service.SslProtocol = "any"
```

In command line you can use

```
--ssl-protocol='any'
```

Comment: No, doesn't work. Probably because those sites don't use SSL/TLS.